# Python Restaring a loop or return to a previous loop on demand

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm a beginner at coding, so please bear with me

I'm trying to write a simple program that allows a user to perform custom commands via input, this program has 2 parts, the first the user inputs a command which calls the correct function to be used and the second part defines the values for the variables in the function.
the code in question (cleaned for this) is the one below.

```
#irrelevant function1 imp():
#irrelevant function2 con():
#irrelevant function3 dis():
def prg():
    vv = ["v","verdadeiro","true","t","1"]
    vf = ["f","falso","false","0"]
    npta=""
    nptb=""
    op = 0
    v = 0
    b = 0
    op = 0
    #irrelevant code here
    while True:
        while op == 0:     
            a = input("insert" ).casefold()
            if a == "imp":
                op=1
            elif a == "dis":
                op=2
            elif a == "con":
                op=3
            elif a == "exit":
                return
            else:
                print("\n wrong input") 

        while True:
            npta=str(input("insert" )).casefold()
            if npta == "abort":
                op = 0
                b = 1
                break
            elif npta == "exit":
                return
            elif npta in vv or npta in vf:
                b = 0
                break
            else:
                print("\n wrong input")    
        while b != 1:
            nptb=str(input("insert" )).casefold()
            if nptb == "abort":
                op = 0
                break
            elif nptb == "exit":
                return
            elif nptb in vv or nptb in vf:
                break
            else:
                print("\n wrong input")      
        if op !=0:
        v = imp(vv, npta, nptb) if op == 1 else con(vv, npta, nptb) if op == 2 else dis(vv, npta, nptb)
        op=0
prg()
```

I feel like what I am doing is super messy although working, is there any simpler way of restarting a loop or make some sort of call for a program to go to a previous loop? Let's say I'm on the second part of my program, the one below

```
    while True:
        npta=str(input("insert" )).casefold()
        if npta == "abort":
            op = 0
            b = 1
            break
        elif npta == "exit":
            return
        elif npta in vv or npta in vf:
            b = 0
            break
        else:
            print("\n wrong inpuy")    
    while b != 1:
        nptb=str(input("inser" )).casefold()
        if nptb == "abort":
            op = 0
            break
        elif nptb == "exit":
            return
        elif nptb in vv or nptb in vf:
            break
        else:
            print("\n wrong inpuy")      
    if op !=0:
    v = imp(vv, npta, nptb) if op == 1 else con(vv, npta, nptb) if op == 2 else dis(vv, npta, nptb)
    op=0
```

Is there a way to return to the previous while if I type abort?
I know this might be a dumb question since the program works, I am just feeling that I am not approaching the wisest solution/algorithm.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put both loops into another while

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to put both of the loops into another loop so when the last loop finishes, it will go to the first loop again because of the outer loop.